# How do you Convert Multiple Categorical (Factor)values into binary values?

Tags: r, binary

I'm having some trouble with the following:

I have a list with 6 different factors:

1     stand

2     stand

3     walk

4     downstairs

5     sit

6     stand

7     lay

8     walk

How can I convert these factors into a binary list in which walk is considered 1 and not walking is 0?

Output:

1     0

2     0

3     1

4     0

5     0

6     0

7     0

8     1

Currently, when I try something like this, I get the following accompanying error.

> test[1] <- 0

Warning message:

In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = 0) : invalid factor level, NA generated

I don't completely understand why I'm getting the error I'm getting.
Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Please see this article [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's unclear what you've tried.

Comment: Also, tag a language. Based on your name, I'm guessing [tag:R].

Comment: Just do a comparison: `test == "walk"`

Comment: Awesome, thank you.


This code worked: test[test == "walk"] <- 1